# How to scrape just the product id from html?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am getting everything but just the product id or "diamond-data-id" on the website HTML code.

I am trying to extract all product ids into a csv file so I can scrape all the product pages that are valid and not go through all the 9 million pages which have error/404 pages.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
import time
import nltk
import string
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import re

url = 'https://www.bluenile.com/diamond-search?track=NavDiaSea'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the html you are downloading from 'https://www.bluenile.com/diamond-search?track=NavDiaSea' doesn't contain any product ids.

When looking at the requests the page does while loading (using a tool like the Firebug plugin for Firefox) you will see that the site is doing some requests in the background to load product data.

These request download product data in JSON format from URLs like https://www.bluenile.com/api/public/diamond-search-grid/v2?country=USA&language=en-us&currency=USD&startIndex=0&pageSize=200&shape=RD&hasVisualization=false&sortColumn=price&sortDirection=asc&_=1492285917847

Just try the above URL in your browser, it might also deliver most if not all other product data you want to scrape.

Then experiment with adjusting the parameters, especially 'startIndex', 'shape' but also the sorting parameters as it seems they aren't accepting a startIndex > 1000.

For example:

https://www.bluenile.com/api/public/diamond-search-grid/v2?country=USA&language=en-us&currency=USD&startIndex=200&pageSize=200&shape=RD&hasVisualization=false&sortColumn=price&sortDirection=asc&_=1492285917847

https://www.bluenile.com/api/public/diamond-search-grid/v2?country=USA&language=en-us&currency=USD&startIndex=400&pageSize=200&shape=RD&hasVisualization=false&sortColumn=price&sortDirection=asc&_=1492285917847

https://www.bluenile.com/api/public/diamond-search-grid/v2?country=USA&language=en-us&currency=USD&startIndex=600&pageSize=200&shape=RD&hasVisualization=false&sortColumn=price&sortDirection=asc&_=1492285917847

https://www.bluenile.com/api/public/diamond-search-grid/v2?country=USA&language=en-us&currency=USD&startIndex=800&pageSize=200&shape=RD&hasVisualization=false&sortColumn=price&sortDirection=asc&_=1492285917847

... and so on ...

By testing various combinations for the parameters you'll be able to download most if not all of their product info including their product IDs.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! Follow-up question, I was able to do one request for 300 data records, but how do we continue to get unique product ids? from the same URL or how do I iterate through the 500 requests to get up to 140K+ product ids?  Thank you in advance...

Comment: Adjusted my answer. You have to modify the parameters in this URL to get more than the initial results.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much!